# How to find infimum and supremum of $\{x∈\mathbb{Q}^+∣x^2\le2\}$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum, rational-numbers

$$x^2≤2$$
$$-\sqrt2\le x\le\sqrt2$$

How to proceed for this domain?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Did you mean $-\sqrt2\le x \le \sqrt2$ with $x$ in place of $x^2$?

Comment: Next take into account the part $x \in Q^+$.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner yes , i updated the question an edit went wrong.

Comment: ok which means no irrationals should be accepted and only positive rationals.. here the least upper bound appears as rad 2 and the greatest lower bound appears as -rad 2.. @GEdgar

Comment: You said "only positive rationals".  But you did not use that to restrict your inequalities.

Comment: we should find a rational positive number to substitute the rad 2 ? or it doesn't exist? @GEdgar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$A=\{x\in\mathbb{Q}^+:x^2\le2\}=\{x\in\mathbb{Q}:0\le x\le2^{\frac{1}{2}}\}\implies \inf A=0, \sup A=2^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Comment: Thanks! so the condition x∈Q+ doesn't require sup A and inf A to be of the same domain?

Comment: @Mixture I think you should check the definition of supremem and infimum, they refer to the least upper bound and the greatest lower bound, so in this case you need the interval for $x$, and determine the least & upper bound for this interval.

Comment: Thankful, will get more into it